Do we only care about the "permanent response" (i.e. the particular solution to the ODE) in a Linear System?
When we consider the output of a Linear System, say the driven $RLC$ electric circuit, are we solely concerned about the "permanent" response (as opposed to the "transitory" response)? By permanent I mean the particular solution to the ODE and by transitory I mean the homogeneous solution to the ODE.
In case the answer is "we only care about the permanent response" I have a side-remark: the homogeneous solution space being a vector space, why don't we include it in the Linear System?

That depends on your specific application but there are use cases where we are definitively interested in the transient response. When you turn on an electrical device, you really want to know whether the in-rush current trips the circuit breaker even if the steady state current is low.

@PeterK. Well I think the homogeneous solution (without RHS forcing term) is the Lightly / Critically / Over damped response. This damped response can't exist forever, while the particular solution is the other one.

Ah, I see. I've not heard "permanent" and I think it confuses the issue (as it clearly did for me!) :-)
